# php pdo bind_param error

Tags: php, json, pdo

I'm running into error with an insert into table

JSON:

```
{"machine":"1","postage":"1","tracking":"1","lve":"1","notice":"4","content":"12","refresh":"1","location":"cityname"}
```

How can I get this going?

thx

*EDIT*
fixed the errors you guys mentioned

```
function addOptions ($postData, $dbh) {

//print_r($postData);
$result = json_decode($postData);
//$location = $result->location;
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO options (location, display_time ,content_time, refresh_time, machine_data, postage_data, tracking_data, lve_data) 
                    VALUES (:location, :display_time, :content_time, :refresh_time, :machine_data, :postage_data, :tracking_data, :lve_data) 
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                    display_time= :display_time, refresh_time= :refresh_time, machine_data= :machine_data, content_time= :content_time, postage_data= :postage_data, tracking_data= :tracking_data, lve_data= :lve_data";
$preparedStatement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$preparedStatement->bindParam(':location', $result->location);
$preparedStatement->bindParam(':display_time', $result->display);
$preparedStatement->bindParam(':content_time', $result->content);
$preparedStatement->bindParam(':refresh_time', $result->refresh);
$preparedStatement->bindParam(':machine_data', $result->machine);
$preparedStatement->bindParam(':postage_data', $result->postage);
$preparedStatement->bindParam(':tracking_data', $result->tracking);
$preparedStatement->bindParam(':lve_data', $result->lve);
$preparedStatement->execute();

}
```

now i get this error msg

Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin\include\function.php on line 186

Comment: Looks like you just forgot to call `$preparedStatement = $dbh->prepare($sql);`

Comment: That doesn't fully explain why it complains of a boolean instead of a non-object or undefined variable. Is there more code you have not shown?

Comment: Where is your call to `prepareStatement`?

Comment: Oh, I just scrolled right---. An `INSERT` statement never has a `WHERE` clause, because it is only capable of adding new rows. Was this supposed to be an `UPDATE`?

Comment: Setup your PDO connection to throw useful errors. By default, PDO errors silently.  `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: @ ethrbunny missed to copy the prepare, sorry for this.

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs `bind_param` that is `mysqli_` and not PDO. Plus, INSERT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html doesn't have a `WHERE` clause, but UPDATE does. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html <= FYI.

Comment: Ah, and another thing - PDO's method is called `bindParam()`, not `bind_param()` (which is that of MySQLi)

Comment: Read up on both *different* methods http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements and http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: So, where are we at with this question? It doesn't seem to be going anywhere. Have you tried the answers below, and is your DB connection in fact PDO?

Comment: @manga Updated my answer hope it solves your problem ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You forgot to create your prepared statement, try this before you bind the parameters:</strike>

```
$preparedStatement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```

**EDIT:**

Just change this:

(Since you already bind the parameters you just can execute the query! Otherwise the parameter for execute would include the parameters for the prepared statement)

```
$preparedStatement->execute($sql);
```

to this:

```
$preparedStatement->execute();
```

For more information about the PDO execute() command see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

And a quote from there:

> public bool PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] )

Comment: There's more going on here than the OP has posted. There must be because the variable wouldn't even be defined, and the SQL INSERT syntax is confused.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yeah, you're probably right! (Just read your comment about the WHERE clause, which is very weird)

Answer (score 1):

Few mistakes:

1. Add the pdo prepare:

   ```
   $preparedStatement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
   ```
2. change all your bind_param to this:

   ```
   $preparedStatement->bindParam(':display', $result->display);
   ```
3. add the execute into a if condition so you see if it worked:

   ```
   if( $preparedStatement->execute() === FALSE){

      Throw new \Exception('Bad query insertion!');
   }
   ```